# Isn't there something fundamentally wrong with adding a csrf to a form?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, csrf, zend-form-element, csrf-protection

If the user opens two forms of the same kind, one will have a csrf error,

I myself being a multi-talented, multi-tasking with a robot mentality, absolute beast am used to opening multiple tabs and doing things in crazy ways, csrf checks reduce me into a normal person.

What can be done about this?

Sorry, forgot to mention this is about zend framework's csrf element

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No one ever said that only 1 CSRF token can be live at a one time.  I typically keep an array of valid tokens and will accept any of them.  If only one form instance is opened, only one token, but still works the same way.

Comment: This is probably the ideal way to solve it. Just want to mention (because of the ZF tags) that you may need to modify the built in CSRF element in ZF to accomodate for this - I don't recall the built in one will work very well.

Comment: Indeed, the built in one won't allow 'multiple tabs' but a modified version allowing single-use tokens would be a very welcome addition.